# What quality management frameworks are used (appropriate) today - especially in software development?

Tags: software-development, quality-management

There were ISO 9001 (and adapted version for IT TickIT), CMMI - capability maturity model, Six Sigma, IEEE software development standards and so on. All that was intended for software quality management. What is left from this and what is being applied from this in today (as of 2016)? Maybe there is some good reference, practice report, review about the current situation in industry and the recommended best practices from the scientists?

It seems to me that agile approach is used widely and there are no predefined standards except for team approved methdologies and practices.

Comment: Are you trying to ask what the statistical prevalence is of all frameworks? I'm not personally aware of any meaningful studies that could answer that, and even if there were such studies, I doubt they could be truly exhaustive.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. Most of these things are not opposed to each other - it's possible to have an organization that is following ISO 9001 (or industry-specific variant) for it's quality management system while implementing CMMI and following the agile methods, while using the various IEEE standards for systems and software engineering. From what I've seen, the implementation of ISO 9001 is driven by industry standards and customer expectations. Things like CMMI, Lean, Six Sigma, the IEEE standards, and the agile methods provide a process framework.

Comment: No, I am not interested in statistics. I do know that ISO 9001 and CMMI can be integrated (they can be integrated even with agile methods). Simply, I need to learn about software quality standards and processes and I seek motivation. The reality is that one large firm in our country has dropped CMMI certification, University has dropped software quality course and there is less buzz about these things. So - should they belong to the past and are there some new practices? Or avoiding CMMI and software quality course is just local factor that I experience?

Comment: I wonder if the additional costs of implementing these "branded" quality management systems has lead to the quieting of the call for them. Implementing CMMI 5 was crazy expensive and likely only used for government systems. As the government has had to reduce payments they may no longer be looking for this level of documentation and assurance. Aside from that, I'm still running across ISO9000 and CMMI for developments using waterfall processes. I'm not seeing much QMS in Agile environments.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, *Quality Management Frameworks*, have been replaced by the aim to pass the Acceptance Test.

In **smartphone** software development, the de-facto software quality standards are defined by the various App-Stores.

If you want to safely disseminate your app you need to pass their tests.

In **web server** development, the final product will likely undergo some 3rd party penetration test.

So it seems that the field of QMF has splintered, and if you want to learn about it, you need to discover the acceptance test relevant to the type of product you are building.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ISO 25010](https://www.iso.org/standard/35733.html) "Systems and software engineering — Systems and software Quality Requirements and Evaluation (SQuaRE) — System and software quality models"